# extends a class with Kotlin annotation is possible?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I m using spring, kotlin and aws messaging, and i was wondering if its possible to extends a class with an annotation in kotlin.

i was wondering if there is a way to make an annotation to annotate the consumer class like:

```kotlin
@Component
@MessagingAdvice 
class SomeApplicationConsumer(
    private val someService: SomeService
) { ...
```

and extends the MessagingAdvice class

In my project i have alot of aws sqs consumer classes, and i need to extend the class with some MessageExceptionHandler functions, using the extends like this, and i was wondering if there is a most elegant way to do that.

```kotlin
class MessagingAdvice {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)
    @MessageExceptionHandler(MessagingException::class)
    fun handleMessagingException(e: MessagingException) {
        logger.error("this is an error ! ${e.message}")
    }

}
```

```kotlin
@Component
class SomeApplicationConsumer(
    private val someService: SomeService
): MessagingAdvice() {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    @SqsListener(
        deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS,
        value = ["\${queue.name}"]
    )
    fun consume(response: SomeQueueResponse) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just put this in a super class that all your ApplicationConsumers extend?

Comment: sure ! i can, but i m trying to solve it in more elegant way